# If $H$ is Lie subgroup embedded in a Lie group $G$, then $H$ is closed

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I read the demonstration that if $G$ be a Lie group and $H \subset G$ a closed subgroup of $G$. Then $H$
is an embedded Lie subgroup of $G$. The author mentions that the reciprocal is true, but does not prove it. I am trying to demonstrate this, but I am unable to devise a strategy. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $h_n$ is a sequence in $H$ converging to so some $g\notin H$. Find two subsequences $h_{n_i}, h_{n_j}$ such that $h_{n_i}h^{-1}_{n_j}$ converges to $1$ in $G$ but diverging to infinity in the manifold topology of $H$.